# How to make javascript function active in html

Tags: javascript, html

This code came from http://jsfiddle.net/ejqngpn5/ but I apparently am putting the javascript and html portions together incorrectly or am missing something else because it is not working as it did on-line. How is the javascript inserted into and the function invoked in html code? I use AJAX calls in my scripts but don't know to make these two code fragments work together. It should produce, onClick, a multiple check-box list in a drop down menu. Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    </select>   
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () { 
    $('#lstStates').multiselect({ 
        buttonText: function(options, select) {
            console.log(select[0].length);
            if (options.length === 0) {
                return 'None selected';
            }
            if (options.length === select[0].length) {
                return 'All selected ('+select[0].length+')';
            }
            else if (options.length >= 4) {
                return options.length + ' selected';
            }
            else {
                var labels = [];
                console.log(options);
                options.each(function() {
                    labels.push($(this).val());
                });
                return labels.join(', ') + '';
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ Download lib form here with example.

Comment: In the JSFiddle, it works like you said... it is a dropdown witch multiple items and checkboxes net to them. If you are not using it in a JSFiddle, link the external script using `<script src="myjavascriptfile.js"></script> and make sure to add jQuery/AJAX in your html as well.

Comment: did you include the libraries for this? : `bootstrap-multiselect.js` and `bootstrap-multiselect.css`

Answer (score 1):

You should include these resources to your project: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

Comment: this should really be a comment not an answer

Comment: @InvincibleM, You shouldn't add a comment to my answer like this.

Comment: Yes, I thank everyone for their input. I had never used jQuery before and didn't recognize the script form. .Now I have - and it works fine. My best to all.