# How to make the script work in a program with html and java?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The script doesn't seem to be working when I'm running my code on sublime.On the contrary, when I run it in fiddle it does work. Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/m5wbdtLg/  . I can't append the question and dropdown in sublime while it is working fine on fiddle. I'm new to this, please help me out. Thank you.

I have tried including resources like this [[How to make javascript function active in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002692/how-to-make-javascript-function-active-in-html]]) 
I have also tried $(document).ready(function(){..}); &  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

```
 $( "#add" ).click(function()
{var newElement = '<div class="container"><form id ="ques"><label>Question:</label><br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" placeholder="Enter a question"></textarea><br><select name="choice" id="choice" onchange="selectorchecker(this)"><option value="">Select choices</option><option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option><option value="radiobtn">Radio Button</option></select></form>';
$( "#ques" ).append( $(newElement) );
});

  function selectorchecker(sel) {
    document.getElementById("chkbox_choice").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("rdbtn_choice").style.display = "none";if (sel.value) {
     var show = sel.value=="checkbox"?"chkbox_choice":"rdbtn_choice";
     document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
 }
}

   function addRowchk(tableID) {

      var table_chk = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount_chk = table_chk.rows.length;
      var row_chk = table_chk.insertRow(rowCount_chk);

      var cell1_chk = row_chk.insertCell(0);
      var element1_chk = document.createElement("input");
      element1_chk.type = "checkbox";
      element1_chk.name="chkbox[]";
      cell1_chk.appendChild(element1_chk);

      var cell2_chk= row_chk.insertCell(1);
      var element2_chk = document.createElement("input");
      element2_chk.type = "text";
      element2_chk.name = "txtbox[]";
      cell2_chk.appendChild(element2_chk);
    }

function deleteRowchk(tableID) {
 try {
    var table_chk = document.getElementById(tableID);
     var rowCount_chk = table_chk.rows.length;

     for(var i=0; i<rowCount_chk; i++) {
       var row_chk = table_chk.rows[i];
       var chkbox = row_chk.cells[0].childNodes[0];
       if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
         table_chk.deleteRow(i);
         rowCount_chk--;
         i--;
       }
     }
   }catch(e) {
   alert(e);
 }
}

function addRowRd(tableID) {

      var table_rd = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount_rd = table_rd.rows.length;
      var row_rd = table_rd.insertRow(rowCount_rd);

      var cell1_rd = row_rd.insertCell(0);
      var element1_rd = document.createElement("input");
      element1_rd.type = "radio";
      element1_rd.name="rdbtn[]";
      cell1_rd.appendChild(element1_rd);

      var cell2_rd= row_rd.insertCell(1);
      var element2_rd= document.createElement("input");
      element2_rd.type = "text";
      element2_rd.name = "txtbox[]";
      cell2_rd.appendChild(element2_rd);
    }

function deleteRowRd(tableID) {
 try {
   var table_rd = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount_rd = table_rd.rows.length;

   for(var i=0; i<rowCount_rd; i++) {
   var row_rd = table_rd.rows[i];
   var rdbtn = row_rd.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if(null != rdbtn && true == rdbtn.checked) {
    table_rd.deleteRow(i);
       rowCount_rd--;
       i--;
       }
    }
    }catch(e) {
    alert(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you reformat your question please, it looks a little too messy to read.

Comment: I don't see any Java here. Perhaps you meant *JavaScript*?

Comment: Please post your question in a readable and understandable format?

Answer (score -1):

You randomly use jquery when everything else is vanilla js, why not just use all vanilla js?

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML += '<div class="container"><form id ="ques"><label>Question:</label><br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" placeholder="Enter a question"></textarea><br><select name="choice" id="choice" onchange="selectorchecker(this)"><option value="">Select choices</option><option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option><option value="radiobtn">Radio Button</option></select></form>';
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="ques"></div>
```